# $M$ is complete iff by showing given sequence is cauchy .

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Prove that metric space  $(M,d)$  is complete iff every sequence $(x_n)$ in $M$ satisfying.    $$d(x_n,x_{n+1}) < 1/2^n$$    for all $n$  converges to a point of $M$.

Attempt:
Reverse implication.

Since,

$$d(x_n,x_{n+1}) < 1/2^n$$

for all $n$ to $N
\implies   d(x_n,x_{m}) < 1/2^{m-n}  = \varepsilon _{m,n} \,  $ for all $m>n$ and $ m,n \geq N$  for some natural number $N \implies  (x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence  which converges to point in $M \implies M$ is complete .

Is this right?

How to go for forward implication?
Is it reverse steps of reverse implication .

Comment: No, it is not right. In proving that $M$ is complete, you should *assume* that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, and prove that it is convergent. This is not what you did. You *assumed* that $(x_n)$ satisfies the given condition, and proved that it is Cauchy. That is not what is required to prove that $M$ is complete.

Comment: $(x_n)$ is already convergent which  is mentioned in the question. I proved that the given sequence also satisfies cauchy criterion by using the given $d(x,y) $

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it is imperative that you understand what you need to prove: that every Cauchy sequence is convergent. What you proved is "Every sequence that satisfies the condition is also Cauchy and converges". What if there is a Cauchy sequence which **does not** satisfy the given condition? That's why your proof is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose first that $(M, d)$ is complete. Consider a sequence $(x_n)$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$d(x_n, x_{n+1}) < \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. There exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\frac{1}{2^{N-1}} < \varepsilon$$

Let $p > q \geq N$. You have then
$$d(x_p, x_q) \leq \sum_{k=q}^{p-1} d( x_{k+1},x_k) \leq \sum_{k=q}^{p-1} \frac{1}{2^{k}} = \frac{1}{2^q} \frac{1- \frac{1}{2^{p-q}}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2^{q-1}} - \frac{1}{2^{p-1}} \leq \frac{1}{2^{q-1}} \leq \frac{1}{2^{N-1}} \leq \varepsilon$$

Therefore your sequence is a Cauchy sequence, and because $(M,d)$ is complete, it converges.

Now suppose that every sequence $(x_n)$ such that $d(x_n, x_{n+1}) < \frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n$ converges, and let's prove that $(M, d)$ is complete. Consider a Cauchy sequence $(y_n)$. By definition, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $N_k$ such that for all $p, q \geq N_k$, $$d(y_p,y_q) < \frac{1}{2^k}$$
In particular, the sequence $(N_k)$ can be choosen increasing, so you get that for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$,
$$d(y_{N_k},y_{N_{k+1}}) < \frac{1}{2^k}$$

Define now the sequence $x_k = y_{N_k}$. You have $d(x_k, x_{k+1}) < \frac{1}{2^k}$ for all $k$, so by assumption, $(x_k)$ converges. Let $l$ be the limit of $(x_k)$. Let's prove that $l$ is also the limit of $(y_n)$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Because $(x_k)$ converges to $l$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \geq N$, 
$$d(y_{N_k},l) =d(x_k, l) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

Moreover, there exists $N'$ such that $\frac{1}{2^{N'}} < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ : by definition, for all $k \geq N'$, for all $n \geq N_k$, you have that 
$$d(y_n, y_{N_k}) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$

Let's define $N'' = N_{\max{N,N'}}$ : for all $n \geq N''$, you have then that 
$$d(y_n, l) \leq d(y_n, y_{N_k})  + d(l, y_{N_k})  < \varepsilon$$

So $(y_n)$ converges to $l$. That is sufficient to ensure that $(M,d)$ is complete.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

For the reverse implication, suppose that $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M$. Then inductively construct a subsequence $(x_{p(n)})_n$ such that $d(x_{p(n)}, x_{p(n+1)}) < \frac1{2^n}$. Hence $(x_{p(n)})_n$ converges to some $x \in M$. Now show that $x_n \to x$.

For the forward implication, assume that $M$ is complete and that a sequence $(x_n)_n$ satisfies $d(x_{n+1}, x_n) < \frac1{2^n}$. Then for $m > n$ we have
\begin{align}
d(x_m, x_n) &\le d(x_{m}, x_{m-1}) + d(x_{m-1}, x_{m-2}) + \cdots + d(x_{n+1}, x_n)\\
&\le \frac1{2^{m-1}} + \frac1{2^{m-2}}+\cdots + \frac1{2^n}\\
&= \frac1{2^n}\left(1+\frac12 +\cdots + \frac1{2^{m-n-1}}\right)\\
&= 2\left(\frac1{2^n} - \frac1{2^m}\right)
\end{align}
From here conclude that $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy and hence convergent.

Comment: It is already given in question that sequence $(x_n) $ converges to some point in M . Why you are proving it ?( Reverse Implication )

Comment: @Doraemon No, we have that $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy and we need to *prove* that it converges to a point in $M$. We need to somehow use the assumption that any sequence $(y_n)_n$ satisfying $d(y_n, y_{n+1}) < \frac1{2^n}$ converges in $M$.

Comment: Means your $(x_n)$ is different from what is present  in question.

Comment: @Doraemon Yes, $(x_n)_n$ in the "reverse implication" part of my answer stands for an arbitrary Cauchy sequence in $M$.

Comment: I don't understand why your answer is downvoted by someone ?

Comment: I think your final expression will be  $  =2(\frac{1}{2^n} - \frac{1}{2^m})$

Comment: @Doraemon Yes, of course, thanks. Maybe that's why it was downvoted.